# how can i make have the specific type infered based on argument passed

Tags: typescript

I'd like to make it so that my get widget function result automatically returns the specific type based on the parameter I pass to the function. Is there a way to do this in typescript?
As of right now it gives me one of the possible types as return but not the specific one corresponding to the key provided.

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICiY2AthADYgCCuuUArmgMIhoYASAKgLIAyhKqTaJw6FABMAzgm79BIYWgQBvYAg0IwALgQAKAJQIAvAD4EANyhIJAbmABfYKEixEqdFjwFiZSiB5UJAAxKChPOQEhEQQxNmlZXijFGLVNBABPXUMTcysbeydQFAZSIhJyKg44UgoFJTgpADkyAjTNX0qAoNDwjBMEAHJO-wBaUiDRzDDPQYAadQ6K-1p6JjhWdhgB4eWqUbw1tFH8LfnHZw8MHHxyvyqauui0GXaNAG0Rh9r6kWbWgB0XxodEYLBEGAAurpgaswRsITBIr80At0p89iBqj9no0WsIgZjAigQjMoTCiT0yUikii4AsiuBoPAEJgmLg4EgoCgEABzEBwADqNn5cD0cGwvPxIAp9yxjzp-2ERjeCBgAoYMB5EiguFKIgBAEcGBgMgBlEBUDmwAA8wOxTxSL3ecAyEBAUEwCAlUtakNM4sl0oMhWc9BQUkQ6pkxj5AuFElFentCtxSpAhLlcPWm08BmcQA)

```js
export interface ExampleAccountCenterHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
    x: () => void;
}

export interface ExampleMiniFooterHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
    y: () => void;
}

enum ExampleHtmlElementsName {
    ExampleMiniFooter = 'Example-mini-footer',
    ExampleAccountCenter = 'Example-account-center',
}

interface ExampleHtmlElements {
    [ExampleHtmlElementsName.ExampleAccountCenter]: ExampleAccountCenterHTMLElement,
    [ExampleHtmlElementsName.ExampleMiniFooter]: ExampleMiniFooterHTMLElement,
}

export function getWidget(tagName: ExampleHtmlElementsName) {
    return document.querySelector<ExampleHtmlElements[typeof tagName]>(tagName);
}

const res = getWidget(ExampleHtmlElementsName.ExampleAccountCenter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `typeof` on `tagName` is not a good idea. You gave `tagName` the explicit type `ExampleHtmlElementsName`, and that is excactly what `typeof tagName` will evaluate to. Instead, make the function generic.

```
export function getWidget<T extends ExampleHtmlElementsName>(tagName: T) {
    return document.querySelector<ExampleHtmlElements[T]>(tagName);
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICiY2AthADYgCCuuUArmgMIhoYASAKgLIAyhKqTaJw6FABMAzgm79BIYWgQBvYAg0IwALgQAKAJQIAvAD4EANyhIJAbmABfYKEixEqdFjwFiZSiB5UJAAxKChPOQEhEQQxNmlZXijFGLVNBABPXUMTcysbeydQFAZSIhJyKg44UgoFJTgpADkyAjTNX0qAoNDwjBMEAHJO-wBaUiDRzDDPQYAadQ6K-1p6JjhWdhgB4eWqUbw1tFH8LfnHZw8MHHxyvyqauui0GXaNAG0Rh9r6kWbWgB0XxodEYLBEGAAurpgaswRsITBIr80At0p89iBqj9no0WsIgZjAigQjMoTCiT0yUikii4AsiuBoPAEJgmLg4EgoCgEABzEBwADqNn5cAAPFxYmBxAlgdinikXviQKY9HBsLzlbouEY3ggYAKGDAeRIoLhSiIAQBHBgYDIAZRAVA5sDFcsedKk7y4kNV6s1rQMhWc9BQUkQBpkxj5AuFElFendOMVeMBsNB602ngMziAA)

Comment: this actually did it, thanks!